# Oracle 10g - JAXB unmarshalling is not working as expected

Tags: oracle10g, jaxb, webservice-client, unmarshalling

We're using Oracle 10g application server and deployed the Web service and trying to deploy the web service client. Server is working fine i.e.; marshalling is working fine. We're getting the output from the service properly but the search client is not unmarshalling (parsing) the response received. We're using all the tags under same name space so there is no name space problem. Different collections would exists in the XSD. Has anyone faced similar kind of issue? Is there any solution for this?

Thanks

Santhosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... the issue was due to the library which was not running as expected in Java 1.5. We've developed the web service client with JAX-WS 2.2 which was running properly when running with Netbeans IDE 6.8 but not on the standalone server. We've downgraded the Netbeans and modified the libraries to JAX-WS 2.1. It worked...

Good to know. JAX-WS 2.2 is not compatible with Java 1.5